# Dynamically Import Resources into Config.yml in Symfony2

Tags: php, frameworks, dependency-injection, symfony

Below is a pretty standard code block from `config.yml` in Symfony2. I want to dynamically load a different `parameter.ini` based on an external parameter (in my case, I'm getting it from the servers environment variables `SYMFONY__SERVER__VARIABLE`). My only problem seems to by that Sf2 won't take parameters..

For example, this works. But the below doesn't.

```
imports:
    - { resource: parameters.ini }
    - { resource: security.yml }
framework:
    router:          { resource: "%kernel.root_dir%/config/routing.yml" }
```

The below example doesn't. To me, it seems like these two examples would produce the same results since `routing.yml` and `parameters.ini` are in the same directory.

```
imports:
    - { resource: "%kernel.root_dir%/config/parameters.ini" }
    - { resource: security.yml }
framework:
    router:          { resource: "%kernel.root_dir%/config/routing.yml" }
```

The reason I looked at the examples above is because I know `%kernel.root_dir%` works well in other areas of `config.yml`. And it tells me there something other than what I'm doing making it so this code doesn't work.

Ultimately, this is what I'd like to do.

```
imports:
        - { resource: "%server.variable%-parameters.ini" }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're trying to do what I was doing.  And while I'm not directly answering your question (how to user parameters in a imports directive) I think it addresses your issue (loading server-specific config)

[Symfony 2 - multiple server configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10014327/symfony-2-multiple-server-configuration)

Comment: So what you're saying is you can run the load method multiple times in our case, execute `$loader->load( $serverConfig );` to do your server/environment-specific-config.yml along with a specific `parameters.ini` .. you can then load the traditional `$loader->load(__DIR__.'/config/config_'.$this->getEnvironment().'.yml');` .. I'm not 100% yet, but this looks like a solution to me! Thank you!

Comment: couldn't even wait till tomorrow to test it! Really quick and clean solution! Thank you Peter.

Comment: Glad it works  FYI, I found I needed to change the order the YAML files were loaded. I'm going to go update my referenced question now.