# Passing "null" encryption from parameters.ini and using it in config.yml

Tags: symfony, configuration, swiftmailer

I am trying to set a null value in `app/config/parameters.ini` and use it in `app/config/config.yml` for the `swiftmailer.encryption` config parameter. I need to set it in parameters.ini because I have different environments that each use different mail configuration.

The [Symfony documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/reference/configuration/swiftmailer.html#encryption) says that this config parameter should be a string value and that "valid values are tls, ssl, or null".

My first guess would be to add `mailer_encryption="null"` to parameters.ini and `encryption: %mailer_encryption%` to config.yml. But that results in an error:

> "InvalidConfigurationException: Invalid configuration for path "swiftmailer.encryption": The "null" encryption is not supported".

If I use `mailer_encryption=null` or `mailer_encryption=` in parameters.ini, I get another error:

> "InvalidConfigurationException: Invalid configuration for path "swiftmailer.encryption": The "" encryption is not supported".

If I stop referencing the parameter by changing config.yml to `encryption:`, it works but this doesn't solve my objective.

I am using Symfony 2.0.15, which includes Swiftmailer with it. [This is the 2.0 branch](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/tree/2.0).

How can I get this working?

Comment: You could try to use the `~` like this: `mailer_encryption = ~` in your ini file.

Comment: @Sgoettschkes That throws "ErrorException: Warning: syntax error, unexpected END_OF_LINE in /path/to/parameters.ini"

Comment: Can you just create different yml files for each environment, something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10014327/symfony-2-multiple-server-configuration

Comment: @Squazic For security purposes, I want to keep all of that stuff in parameters.ini. The parameters.ini file is not committed to the repo.

Comment: AFAIK, you can use yml format of parameters file. So try to create parameters.yml and import it to your config.yml

Comment: @Ziumin That fixed it. Add an answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK, you can use yml format of parameters file. So try to create parameters.yml and import it to your config.yml

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried with ~ ? as in yml configs.